# Clarification for declined "Not an answer" flag

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, not-an-answer

I'm trying to understand why a specific "Not an answer" flag was declined.

The question was asking about how to ensure a developer has a valid copy of Xcode. One of the answers was simply:

> Please follow the instructions given by Apple here

where the word "here" is a link to a page on Apple's website. I flagged this as not an answer because it is a link-only answer. Someone seemed to agree because after my flag, the comment *"While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes."* was added.

But the flag was declined with *"declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer"*.

Why? It wasn't inaccurate. It wasn't wrong. It's just a link.

The OP actually deleted their answer after the comment but I'm trying to understand why the flag was declined. It doesn't seem appropriate in this case.

BTW - I found [this meta discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185073/how-do-i-properly-use-the-not-an-answer-flag/185074#185074) and link-only answers are not listed in either the "When should I use this flag" or the "When should I not use this flag".

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer

Comment: could it be that the answer got deleted? IIRC, all flags are declined when the post that was flagged gets removed

Comment: @Patrice I've always had flags automatically become "helpful" when the OP deleted their answer that I flagged.

Comment: @theB your link-only comment seems to agree that my flag should not have been declined.

Comment: @rmaddy I could definitely be wrong on that assumption. I'm just saying I think I remember it being mentioned somewhere. For what it's worth, you are 100% right. The flag WAS appropriate (IMHO)

Comment: @rmaddy - If you remove the "here" what would you have done with the answer? Do you think without the link it makes no attempt to answer the question? I agree that its a crappy answer, but I disagree that it qualifies as NAA.

Comment: @TheB so... on pretty much any question, answering "just read the docs" would be valid? I don't fully agree here

Comment: @theB If the answer was simply "Please follow the instructions given by Apple" with no link then I absolutely would have flagged as NAA since it makes no attempt to provide an answer and at best it should just be a comment.

Comment: @Patrice - Certainly not on every question, but in this case the question seems to be one that can only be resolved by referring to Apple's own documentation.  Of course quoting the relevant information _in addition_ to the link would have been better.

Comment: @theB I still disagree. I can expand that concept to "well you could edit your code until it works" for questions that docs won't solve. These are NOT answers. We can make the pedantic point that it DOES attempt to solve, but I'm still considering these as NAAs

Comment: @Patrice - Nothing I've said suggests that `well you could edit your code until it works` would be an appropriate answer in any context.  For this _specific_ question referring someone to the Apple documentation solves the problem, unless the documentation doesn't show how to validate a copy of XCode. Let's flag and close the question, since any answer will have to be some form of `The documentation says` + `Quote` + `link`

Comment: I've had many NAA flags accepted on link-only answers.

Comment: I think it's debatable, which is probably why it happened. It's a _bad_ answer, but it's not _quite_ a 'link only' answer. I'd probably agree and vote to delete, but I'd imagine someone thought it constituted a 'refer to apple's docs' and called that an answer (albeit a bad one)

Answer (score 3):

There is a lot of leniency given to answers that attempt to answer questions, even if it is along the lines of a small sentence and a link.

However, this case seems to be egregious. *It is hard to tell without a link to the deleted post* how involved the link was and if it was possible to find at a later time should the link age. This is important, because if the link itself contains a decent amount of information then it is more relevant than if the link is simply to http://www.apple.com .

- If there was enough information in the link to qualify the answer as attempting to answer the question, as the moderator seemed to feel, then that is why your flag was declined.
- If the link itself didn't have any information then the flag should have been actioned because it didn't attempt to answer the question, and all it said was "follow the directions" (rtfm) which is not an answer.

Sometimes mods don't get every flag right, although in this case I would assume they did because of the general high percentage success rate they have.